# Headers for PNG image output to make sure it gets cached at browser?

Tags: php, caching, http-headers, browser, png

I have images (PNG) that are generated dynamically and will be embedded in websites and forums. When an image gets posted on a very busy page, there are a lot many connections to service for something that doesn't change often. I want to tell the browser for how long to cache it.

So what headers do I need? Currently, I have:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=86400
Content-Type: image/png
```

It seems that the browser is not caching the image (it is about 20-30kb). What else would be necessary?

Edit:
This is an example image, I already have an URL with `.png` extension:
https://images.carspending.com/sigimg/5734/user/honda-accord-2-4i-executive-tourer_medium.png

Comment: It would certainly make it easier to the browser if you had an URL that actually looks like an image (eg: `http://www.example.com/images/myimage.png` rather than `http://www.example.com/my_script.php?image=93895`)

Comment: I already do that, edited post.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The final thing that worked was:

```
header('Pragma: public');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=86400');
header('Expires: '. gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', time() + 86400));
header('Content-Type: image/png');
```

Now the browser does not make requests for the image when loading a page with embeded one.

Comment: Can you explain why this answers the question?

Comment: At the time it was answered (6 years ago) it did solve the problem. If a png resource with all of these headers was loaded on an external page, it would be properly cached. Isn't it working for you?

Comment: It does not work for me, I'm on Google Chrome 71 and these headers only work if the `png` is in the browser session, once Crome restarted it loads images from the internet again. I also tried `Cache-control: immutable, public, max-age..., stale-while-revalidate...`, `access-control-allow-origin`, `timing-allow-origin`, nothing seems to work...

Answer (score 8):

Make sure you also add public as so:

```
header('Cache-Control: max-age=86400, public');
```

[Read this also](http://yslow.org/user-guide/), is very helpful.

Comment: The correct one is: 
header('Pragma: public');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=86400');
 Buy you gave me the idea

Comment: @Veseliq: I'm glad. I'm no PHP developer so I took a WILD guess ;) And good that you set the Expires date in GMT format; otherwise, it would not have worked either.

Answer (score 2):

An `Expires` header should help.

```
header('Expires: '. gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', time() + 86400));
```