# How to create a link with uuid?

Tags: php, uuid

May be I'm asking a wrong question, I just don't know how to define it more specific, sorry about that.

I want to create links (*src in img tag*)  that looks like that : 
"*bla-bla.com/**7e0cfd63-dfc1-4038-a859-ff201dea7b65***"
and be able to "decode" it back.

Reason why>

My links (*src in img tag*) are looking like that now "*myDomain/somefolder/image1.jpg*" , so if user will change "*image1.jpg*" to "*image2.jpg*" he will get a "direct access" (I think it's called like that).

So I want to prevent "direct access", but still be able to share links.

May be I'm over-complicating the issue and there is another - easy way to do it, or some php extension for this job, please let me know.

Server:
win 2012 r2
Apache + php5 + MySQL

P.S.

"7e0cfd63-dfc1-4038-a859-ff201dea7b65" - this is a UUID, right?
I saw it in youtube video links.

Google search gave a lot of results for UUID/GUID scripts/technics/how it works and so on, but I was not able to find an implementation for links...

P.P.S

if you go to my profile image here on stackoverflow:

> https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4141ef5b3f1196534e59f42f76fe0d0**f**?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1

and change f to d you will get a different image

> https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4141ef5b3f1196534e59f42f76fe0d0**d**?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1

This is what i don't want to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using:

- `mod_rewrite`
- a decoding php script and
- your database to map UUIDs to paths

#### `mod_rewrite`

You use this to redirect all URLs that match a *fake* folder to the decoding script. Naming the fake folder `imgs`, apache configuration would look like (not tested):

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^/img/(.*)$ get_image.php?uuid=$1 [L]
```

This should match a URL like `/img/7e0cfd63-dfc1-4038-a859-ff201dea7b65` and redirect to `/get_image.php?uuid=7e0cfd63-dfc1-4038-a859-ff201dea7b65`. (Your images now source is: `src="/img/7e0cfd63-dfc1-4038-a859-ff201dea7b65"`)

#### get_image.php

This script will use the database to figure out the real location of the image which might as well be outside of the web-root of your application! Apache, however, needs to have access to the file (based on filesystem permissions). For this example lets assume all your images are into `/data/mydomain/images`. Your script might look like:

```
$image_id = $_GET['uuid'];
// ...
$sql = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE uuid='$image_id' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$r = mysql_fetch_array($result);

// DB has the RELATIVE path
$imagepath = "/data/mydomain/images" . $r['path'];

// Produce proper Image
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($imagepath));

echo file_get_contents("$imagepath");
```

Note, that more code will be needed if you want to support more image/mime types.

#### Database

Finally, in your database you need at least two fields in the `images` table:

- `uuid`: The image's UUID. Make that the primary key or if you prefer to have auto_increment integer key, index this column (for performance)
- `rpath`: The relative path to the image in the storage location (for example: `/somefolder/image1.jpg`)

That should be all :). I have not tested any of the above but when put all together should achieve what you want

Comment: For each image/file on server I calculate SHA1, can I use it instead  of UUID? or it is a bad practice for some reason?

Comment: In theory you can use anything you like, but SHA1 is not suggested since it is broken! SHA256 should do it

Comment: @It_Never_Works No worries :)

Comment: First of all this method works fine, does exactly what I want.
In addition it solved my another concern - no need to add alias to directory with images, so they are ONLY accessibly from outside through the script.

**The only disadvantage is - no caching. Is it possible to add caching somehow?**

Comment: @It_Never_Works: Not 100% sure, but wouldn't cache work if you set the correct headers? Example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7324564/3727050)

Comment: You know what? .. You are absolutely right,  if headers set correctly -  cache works !!!